# Get specific time and format to text field

Tags: text, reporting-services, time

I am needing to get the hour in field and convert to a specific time in SSRS expression. Below in my code, but of course I am getting an error.

What I need is if the time is between 00:00 and 00:59, I need it to read 12AM.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
=IIF((Fields!DischargeTime.Value,”HH”) = 00,"12AM" and
    IIF(Fields!DischargeTime.Value,”HH”)  < 01 “12AM”, 
   IIF(Fields!DischargeTime.Value,”HH”)   >= 01,"1AM" and
      IIF(Fields!DischargeTime.Value,”HH”)  < 02, “1AM”)
```

Comment: Please see [ask].  Tell us what you want to do, what you have tried and **what went wrong**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea, if you can adjust your SQL, just handle this in SQL (adjust getdate() to your column):

```
 select  
        case when datepart(hour,getdate()) <= 12 then convert(varchar(50), datepart(hour,getdate())) + 'AM'
             else convert(varchar(50), 24-datepart(hour,getdate())) +'PM'
             end as DischargeHour
```

Or, if you need to keep in SSRS, this seems to work:

```
=Choose(DatePart("h",  Fields!DischargeDate.Value)+1,"12AM","1AM","2AM","3AM","4AM","5AM","6AM","7AM","8AM","9AM","10AM","11AM","12PM","1PM","2PM","3PM","4PM","5PM","6PM","7PM","8PM","9PM","10PM","11PM","12PM")
```

Comment: That is exactly what i did. I added a rather large CASE statement to my SQL Code. This work and i was able to validate about 7000 rows of data, I appreciate your suggestion!

Comment: Cool.  If you would not mind marking this as an answer that would be awesome!

Comment: I do have one more question, how do i sort this in SSRS. Nothing is working. I sorted ASC in my code, but it is not sorting the same in the app. Below are 2 separate codes that i used.                                                                   = Switch (Fields!timeslot.Value = “12AM”, 1,
 Fields!timeslot.Value = “1AM”, 2, 
 Fields!timeslot.Value = “2AM”, 3,
Fields!timeslot.Value = “3AM”, 4,
.....  next is a short example of the other                                                    
 = IIF(Fields!timeslot.Value = “12AM”, 1,
 IIF(Fields!timeslot.Value = “1AM”, 2,

Comment: I wouldn't sort by that column, I'd sort by the actual hour integer column.  It's hard to tell why your sort is not working b/c you can sort in multiple places in ssrs...